# Usage and meaning of 召す【めす】 in different contexts

Tags: words, word-usage

I am going through some Kanji and I was looking for the usage of 召す when I came across the following translation (from jisho.org):

> 1: (Honorific or respectful language) to call; to invite; to send for; to summon;
>
> 2: to eat; to drink;
>
> 3: to put on; to wear;
>
> 4: to ride;
>
> 5: to catch (a cold); to take (a bath); to tickle (one's fancy); to put on (years); 
>   to commit (seppuku);
>
> 6: to do;
>
> 7: (Archaism) honorific suffix used after the -masu stem of a verb

I think I understand 2: 召し上がる is a polite version of eat/drink. There is even one example sentence on jisho.org:

> ワインがお気に召すといいのですが。= I hope the wine is to your taste.

(I think the English translation is not grammatical but I guess the meaning is clear)

But I'm unclear about the other meanings. Could someone provide example sentences on how I can use 召す?

Comment: Addendum: Can you say "I ride a bicycle to work" = "会社に自転車を召して通います"? I doubt it. Or "I am wearing sweater" = "セータを召しています"？

Comment: [The kotobank entry for 召す](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8F%AC%E3%81%99-396081) has examples.

Comment: One sure thing is you never use 召す in your own action, because it's an honorific. セーターを召しています might well describe a third person wearing sweater.

Comment: As an aside, the English ("I hope the wine is to your taste") is perfectly grammatical.  See [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20to%20your%20taste%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) for a few more examples of this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

1: (Honorific or respectful language) to call; to invite; to send for; to summon;

> 父は今年の4月、天に召されました。My father passed away in April.

2: to eat; to drink;

> どうぞ、遠慮なくお召し上がりください。Do help yourself.

3: to put on; to wear;

> その女性はお着物を召されていました。The lady was wearing kimono.

4: to ride;
???

5: to catch (a cold); to take (a bath); to tickle (one's fancy); to put on (years); to commit (seppuku);

> お風邪を召されたようですね。You seem to have caught a cold.
>   お気に召しますか。Do you like it? 
>   お年を召したご婦人 an old lady

6: to do;
???

7: (Archaism) honorific suffix used after the -masu stem of a verb
???

---

This is all I can think of. Sorry!

Comment: There is an "Victorian" usage of お車を召す.

Comment: へ～～・・・古い表現ですかね？

Comment: 何でしょうね。遊ばせ言葉のようなものかもしれないです。検索すると日本語の教科書とおぼしき用例がたくさん出るんですが…（ー_ー）